# Почему небольшой asyncio TCP сервер кидает timeout?

Tags: python, tcp

У меня есть небольшой TCP сервер, который возвращает чуть чуть измененный запрос:

```
import asyncio


class ClientServerProtocol(asyncio.Protocol):

    @staticmethod
    def process_data(resp):
        return "kek" + resp

    def connection_made(self, transport):
        self.transport = transport

    def data_received(self, data):
        resp = self.process_data(data.decode())
        self.transport.write(resp.encode())


def run_server(host, port):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    coro = loop.create_server(
        ClientServerProtocol,
        host, port
    )

    server = loop.run_until_complete(coro)

    try:
        loop.run_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

    server.close()
    loop.run_until_complete(server.wait_closed())
    loop.close()
```

Кажется, он должен работать, но что то идет не так. Функция *run_server* работает без ошибок, но когда я пытаюсь подключится к серверу что бы установить соединение, я получаю таймаут соединения. Что я делаю не так? Сервер запускается из main.py такой строчкой:

```
import server

server.run_server("127.0.0.1", "8888")
```

Comment: Ваш пример отлично работает, с какими параметрами пускаете run_server()? Какая версия python?

Comment: @JK_Action Python 3.7, запускаю запуском соседнего файла (сейчас добавлю в вопрос)

Comment: Вы пытаетесь подключиться к серверу с того же хоста?

Comment: Участник выше высказал правильную мысль. server.run_server("0.0.0.0", "8888") будет работать

Comment: @JK_Action если маршрутизация между хостами есть. А то я очень часто натыкаюсь на вопросы связанные с тем, что сервер в одной домашней сети за провайдерским деревянным маршрутизатором с серым IP-адресом, клиент в другой, а автор удивляется, что не может подключиться.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev на сколько я понимаю 0.0.0.0 на сервере указывает слушать все соединения в том числе извне. В случае указания 127.0.0.1 будут проходить соединения только если клиент запустится на той же машине и стукнется на 127.0.0.1

Comment: @biryulin04 покажите код клиента я тестил через телнет все ок. В том числе и со 127.0.0.1. Кстати какая ОС я тестил на Mint19

Comment: Резюмируя: проблему так и не нашел, но на лини работает. А на последней Windows нет :D

Comment: @biryulin04 будет хорошо, если Вы все же добавите инфу о клиенте и версиях windows на которых запускали